# r ggplot2 object scaled

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I try to plot a Histogram that will be split by facet_grid, and i need to make the y axis scaled,

I found that we can use ..scaled.. like so:
[..scaled.. example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172311/r-geom-density-values-in-y-axis)

But when i use That code

```
ggplot(data,aes(x = v_rate, y=..scaled..)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(group ~ .)
```

I get that error

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'scaled' not found

Was the ..scaled.. object removed from that version of ggplot2? or am I doing something wrong here?

I can't find anything very comprehensive in the docs about that, and when googling that error I find other things entirely

Comment: you probably need to specify this within `geom_density`

Comment: @beetroot could you please provide with an answer and example, and if it works i will be able to accept your answer?

Comment: no, as you did not provide any data, and it's all in the CV post you linked to anyway.

Comment: If you read the help pages on the ggplot2 stat_ and geom_ functions you'll see what computed columns are made available. Hadley did a great job (IMO) documenting these function, and doing that is a definite better first step then "ask the internet".